# How to search singular/plurals in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When I enter word (ex: freshers) I want fresher and freshers records both currently I am getting only freshers records. My code is like this:

```
$search='freshers';
$qry=mysql_query("select count(*) from jobs where job_title like '%$search%' or MATCH(job_title)
AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

when the search word is **freshers** I m getting count as 1200.  When the search word is **fresher** I am again getting count as 2000.

How to get almost same count when I enter either freshers or fresher.

Comment: [php class converting plural to singular or vice versa in english](http://www.kavoir.com/2011/04/php-class-converting-plural-to-singular-or-vice-versa-in-english.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get precisely the same matching-record count from any MySQL technology with a search term that's either singular or plural.

MySQL doesn't have the smarts to know that `freshers` is the plural of `fresher` or `children` is the plural of `child`.  If you want to do this with MySQL you'll have to start your search with the singular form of the word for which you want the plural.

Neither does MySQL know that `mice` is the plural of `mouse`.

If you need automated plural/singular functionality you may want to investigate Lucene or some other natural language search tech. The name of the capability you seek is "stemming."

But you can use FULLTEXT search with terms with trailing asterisks. For example, `'fresher*'` matches `fresher`, `freshers`, and even `fresherola`. This will extend a search from singular to plural. It will not work the other way around. It

```
select count(*) 
  from jobs
 where MATCH(job_title) AGAINST('fresher*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

There are some other modifying characters for boolean mode search terms. They are mentioned here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Pro tip:  `column LIKE '%searchterm%'` is probably the slowest way MySQL offers to search a column. It is guaranteed to scan the whole table.

Pro tip: FULLTEXT search is inherently a bit fuzzy. Expecting crisp record counts from it is probably a path to confusion.

Comment: i am passing variable it contains freshers, mainframes like.... i want fresher and freshers, mainframe and mainframes records.   currently it not getting  iam using where job_title like '%$search%' or  MATCH(job_title) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) both two

Comment: when i pass freshers i am getting fershers only i want fresher also

Answer (score -1):

```
try this
$search='fresher';
$qry=mysql_query("select count(*) from jobs where job_title like '$search%'
```

Comment: hi some times word is middle of line also. it is notshowing records

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.